# Magento 2 Migration Tool - Migrate Settings from 1.9 - 2.0 CE

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, magento2-migration-tool

I am trying to migrate settings from Magento version `1.9.2.2 to 2.0.0 CE`

`mage2\vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\etc\ce-to-ce\1.9.2.2\config.xml` content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../config.xsd">
    <steps mode="settings">
        <step title="Settings step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Settings</step>
            <data>Migration\Step\Stores</step>
        </step>
    </steps>
    <source version="1.9.2.2">
        <database host="localhost" name="magento9" user="root"/>
    </source>
    <destination version="2.0.2">
        <database host="localhost" name="mage2" user="root"/>
    </destination>
    <options>
        <crypt>
            <key><![CDATA[1bc968bd50b96ee18388feaed3bc1f1d]]></key>
        </crypt>
        <map_file>etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.2.2/map.xml</map_file>
        <settings_map_file>etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.2.2/settings.xml</settings_map_file>
    </options>
</config>
```

`settings.xml` is copied from path `mage2\vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\etc\ce-to-ce`

Added `settings.xml.dist` and `map.xml.dist` at location `mage2\vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\etc`

In CMD prompt I am executing commands:

```
D:\xamp\htdocs\mage2\> php bin/magento migrate:settings {vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\etc\ce-to-ce\1.9.2.2\config.xml}
```

But it throws an exception

```
[Migration\Exception]
 Invalid config filename: {vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1
 .9.2.2/config.xml}
 migrate:settings [-r|--reset] config
```

1. How do I run the command successfully to migrate settings?
2. Have I missed any step required for migration?

Please guide.

Reference links
 http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool-install.html
 http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool-configure.html
 http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-migrate-settings.html

Comment: plz show the full path of config.xml {vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\etc\ce-to-ce\1.9.2.2\config.xml}

Comment: I did not get you. The path is already mentioned.Did I miss something here ?

Comment: you have to put absolute path to the magento not in bracket {path}, just ex.php magento migrate:settings /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.2.2/config.xml

Comment: @Rakesh, executing it shows `Migration completed`. But I do not see any  changes reflected in `2.0`. I have changed for ex: base currency setting but its not reflecting the same. How do I verify if the changes are really migrated ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Data migration from Magento 1 to Magento 2.

Your first step is Setting migrate,

command is:

`php bin/magento migrate:settings /var/www/html/{{magento2}}/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/{{magento1 version}}/config.xml`

All `System -> Configuration` settings are migrated in setting migrate.
After completion of setting migrate, You need to check in Magento 2 `Stores -> Configuration` setting.

In migrate setting, From your database table, `core_config_data` have affected.

All Magento 1 settings are migrated to magento 2.

Thanks.

Comment: Not only core_config_data but also store, store_group, store_website are effected.

Comment: [Migration\Exception]
  Invalid config filename: /var/www/html/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.2.0/config.xml

Comment: I cannot see the folder "data-migration-tool" inside /var/www/html/{{magento2}}/vendor/magento/ folder.

Comment: what is diff bw migrate:settings  vs migrate:data shall i run both command during migration process. FYI php bin/magento migrate:settings --reset vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/<edition-to-edition>/<version>/config.xml

Answer (score 1):

Change to the following directory:

```
your-Magento2-root-dir/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/migration-edition/ce-or-version
```

if you are on Linux run this command `cp config.xml.dist config.xml` or on window run this command `copy config.xml.dist config.xml`