# Migration from magento 1.9.2 to magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, migration, magento2-migration-tool

can anyone please provide the process for migrating data, stores and configurations data.
i followed [Magento 2 Migration Tool - Migrate Settings from 1.9 - 2.0 CE](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101339/magento-2-migration-tool-migrate-settings-from-1-9-2-0-ce)

Comment: The thread you provided has the steps. What information do you need? Whether do you need the full steps?

Comment: yes. thanks for sharing.

Comment: @venkataprasad, did you migrate all data without errors?

Comment: @jafarpinjar this migration tool worked for me: [https://next-cart.com/product/magento-to-magento/](https://next-cart.com/product/magento-to-magento/)

Comment: @Jamy does this extension cause any issue?

Comment: @aravind No. It migrated configurable products and bundle products very accurate. They customized the tool to help me move data of extensions too, really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**Install Data Migration Tool**

1)  Check your Magento 2 version :- `sudo php bin/magento --version`

2)  Install Data Migration Tool from repo.magento.com  :-

```
composer config repositories.magento composer https://repo.magento.com                                   
composer require magento/data-migration-tool:<magento_version>
```

3)  Configure Magento 2 Data Migration Tool :-

```
    1 The above file will contain configuration and scripts for migrating from Magento 1 Open Source platform to Magento 2 Open          Source platform.
         <your Magento 2 install dir>/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource

    2 The above file will contain configuration and scripts for migrating from Magento 1 Open Source platform to Magento 2 Commerce.
         <your Magento 2 install dir>/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-commerce

    3 The above file will contain configuration and scripts for migrating from Magento 1 Commerce to Magento 2 Commerce.
         <your Magento 2 install dir>/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/commerce-to-commerce
```

4)  Configuring the migration :-

```
    1 Change to the following directory :-
      <your Magento 2 install dir>/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/<migration edition>/<ce or version>

    2 Rename config.xml.dist to config.xml 
      cp config.xml.dist config.xml

    3 Open config.xml in a text editor.

    4 Specify the following at minimum:

            <database host="localhost" name="Magento1-DB-name" user="DB-username" password="DB-password"/>

            </source>

            <destination>

            <database host="localhost" name="Magento2-DB-name" user="DB-username" password="DB-password"/>

            </destination>

            <options>

            <crypt_key>Magento1-Encrypted-Key</crypt_key>

            </options>
```

5)  Migrate settings :-

```
        php bin/magento migrate:settings --reset vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/<edition-to-edition>/<version>/config.xml
```

6)  Migrate Data :-

```
        php bin/magento migrate:data --auto vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/<edition-to-edition>/<version>/config.xml
```

7)  Migrate Delta :-

```
        php bin/magento migrate:delta --auto vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/<edition-to-edition>/<version>/config.xml
```

Comment: hi @Rathod, composer is not working for me in local. is there any other way to download the tool?

Comment: any error occur ????

Comment: https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool

Comment: hi @Rathod, this is not related to my issue

Comment: link for download manually migration tool

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92349/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-rk-rathod).