# How to migrate data from 2.2.x EE to 2.2.x CE?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.7

I want to migrate my commerce website to an open-source.

I want to migrate the database from EE to CE.

I referred to the below link.

https://blog.magepsycho.com/migrate-downgrade-magento-2-from-enterprise-to-community-edition/

Comment: refereed link provided in question is not working for you ?

Comment: No, because there are huge data with row_is and entity_id difference in product , category and other tables.

Comment: please try steps given in tutorial once, it think it should work.

Comment: I already tried but its not working for me regarding data migration

Comment: if you really need to understand whats going on, create diff between default EE and CE tables, you will get an idea where it all goes. do you understand that some data will be gone? and you will have to accept this loss.

Comment: Hello @barien how are you?

Comment: Hello @BirenPatel or others What was the procedure you followed to do the same?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use magento's [official tool](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-migrate.html) for migration. You need to do little efforts there but you can do it easily.

You can check these questions from MSE:

- [Migrate Magento EE 1.14.3.1 to Magento CE 2.1.7](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/184863/29175)
- [Magento 2 Migration Tool - Migrate Settings from 1.9 - 2.0 CE](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/101339/29175)

Comment: there is no commerce to opensource option in the migration tool?

Comment: there is all explanation. I already did from commerce to opensource with the help of official tool.

Comment: @JarnailS Did you migrate the database from Magento 2.X EE to Magento 2.X CE using  data migration tool? If yes, can you please share some key points?

Comment: No but it can be done as magento2 documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options for you:

- Follow the migration document of Magento here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-tool-configure.html
- You need to find an reliable automated data migration service to help you transfer data such as products, categories and orders from your old store on Magento 1 to Magento 2 smoothly, quickly and safely.

Comment: we can not migrate commerce to open source using this the info from devdocs link

Comment: @BirenPatel There is only one dev document from Magento. You might not migrate commerce to open source because DB structures and codes of EE version is much more different from those of CE version. You can contact Magento support team or find a data migration tool to helps you solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

you wont be able to downgrade while keeping 100% data. be prepared to lose 20%.
while your orders, products and customers will be migrated or exported, other minor data in-between will be lost.

few options available:

1. downgrade with simple drop-in replacement
2. or export data you need from EE and then import to CE